# My PC is making a weird clicking noise

Tags: gpu, fan, noise

Today I cleaned my PC and after that I recognized a weird clicking/ticking noise. It's not really loud and it seems to come from the area around my GPU. It sounds like a fan slightly hitting something, even though it's not at the fan frequency, but you could also describe it as "electrical processing sounds" (the only other description I could think of). The frequency also goes up with the frequency of my GPU fans (even tough the frequency doesn't match with the fans), but I checked them several times and couldn't find anything. I also checked every other fan and the PSU, but I would say the sound is clearly coming from my GPU.

**Specs:** CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 | GPU: Radeon RX 5500 XT | Motherboard: ASRock B450M Pro4 | Storage: 2 SSD's

I checked for coil whine, but im pretty sure that my noise and the are it is coming from is different.

Where is the noise coming from and how to fix it? (if it is fixable)

Comment: It sounds like you should service the GPU not the CPU specifically targeting the GPU fans.  So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Seems like you disturbed something while cleaning.

Comment: My problem is that I have absolutely no idea what is causing it and if its bad or I can ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The frequency also goes up with the frequency of my GPU fans (even tough the frequency doesn't match with the fans), but I checked them several times and couldn't find anything. I also checked every other fan and the PSU, but I would say the sound is clearly coming from my GPU.`

Since you have checked this several times, it sounds like you think this isn't caused by the fans, but you can't say for sure. What you can do is, disconnecting the power cable of your CPU and GPU fans. If the system is idle and not under heavy load, it's pretty safe to do this for a few seconds. This way you can be 100% sure those rotating parts are not creating any noise, because they are not rotating.

You said that you cleaned your PC. With some graphics cards is relatively easy to remove the active cooling part, or even the whole cover plate, so you can see and clean the passive cooling part. Maybe there is something in there, that doesn't belong there. Removing any dust and dirt from the passive cooling part is a good thing to do anyway.

Your [mainboard](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B450M%20Pro4/index.asp) has graphics output connectors, but your [CPU](https://www.amd.com/en/product/8456) doesn't have a builtin graphics capability. So if you remove your graphics card from the mainboard (not while running please), you won't be able to see anything, but you can start your computer without it. Is the clicking noise still present without the graphics device?

If the clicking noise is currently only present when your operating system is fully booted, starting the computer without a graphics device might be not a meaningful test. But maybe you can borrow a different graphics device from someone. Just for this testing purpose, it doesn't have do be anything fancy.

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help me so quickly, but I didn't use my PC for 2 days and now the noise is gone. I just moved my PC a few times around and maybe a cable or something else is not moving or touching anything else anymore. So I guess the problem solved itself.